# Move applications to SD card in Samsung Exhibit?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, app2sd

I have just acquired my first Android phone -- a Samsung Galaxy Exhibit (SGH-T599N) running Android version 4.1.2 (Jelly Bean).  Because the internal storage is fairly small (only 1.34 GB) I've inserted a 16 GB SD card.  I downloaded the program [AppMgr III](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd&hl=en) (formerly app2sd) and attempted to move applications to the SD card; however, when I click on the "On SD Card" tab, I see the following message:

> This device doesn't enable users moving apps to the SD card.  Usually, it's because of the manufacturer removes [sic] the function of moving apps to SD from Android, or a SD card is not inserted.

I see there are many similar threads for other devices, but none explicitly address the Exhibit.  Is there a way (preferably without rooting) to override the manufacturer's removal of this function?

Comment: Without rooting: No. With rooting: See our [app2sd tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info) (and watch out for e.g. *Link2SD*).

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to move apps without root if this function is not supported natively. And 'overriding manufacturer's removal of this function' means you are trying to have extra access apart from native support. And that's possible only when you have root access

If you are willing to root your device, you may check this link:
http://androidforums.com/threads/root-t599-t599n-t599v.763393/